# How do I tweak a setting to ask user to input a value on event when one particular custom field is set to yes?

Tags: trac

I am new to trac and struggling with something. Any help is appreciated.

I have 2 custom fields. Field 1 can be yes or no. and field 2 asks for the number of hours spend.
I am trying to tweak a condition, when field 1 is set to yes, only then user have to put number of hours in the field 2.

I am not able to figure how to put a condition to ask user to input something or a number to be precise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While enforcing user input might sound like a common requirement, Trac developers decided, that it is not basic functionality, and as such it does not belong into core.

However, extending Trac to do what you want is easy, because functional extensions are actively encouraged by the modular [component architecture](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/ComponentArchitecture) and a bunch of extension interfaces, that allow hooking in custom code.

Common way for making certain ticket fields mandatory is to implement an [ITicketManipulator](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints/trac.ticket.api.ITicketManipulator) according to your requirements. I suggest you look at existing code like [TicketValidatorPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TicketValidatorPlugin). Sure, its always better to reusing existing code and possibly contribute to improve it instead of reinventing the wheel over and over again.

Comment: The first field which i have is a custom component, which defines if the ticket is ready for closure. If ready for closure is set to 'Yes', then user need to put in the hours spent. For this I am trying ticketvalidatorplugin. 

validates = spent_hours
spent_hours.rule = .close .yes
is this correct??

Another thing which I was trying is to use this command
#spent_hours.invalid_if =
#spent_hours.invalid_when = .close .Yes

Still I am no where near the solution. Where exactly am i wrong??